# Javascript-styling an id or class wont work when loaded text from online url into div.innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I do is I use XMLHttpRequest() to load plain text into a div's innerHTML..
The online text file contains something like this:
`<div class="a_class" id="a_id">Text</div>`

My html already contains a class like ".a_class" and what I load, it applies the style perfectly to it.
But I can't use Javascript to change the loaded elements, is there a way to style the loaded elements by Id or Class? When I change all elements by class, those having that class wont change..

**It works now! I just made sure that the script runs after loading completes..**

Comment: You have to check if that div element has loaded completely. After making sure that the div element is fully loaded you can run your js commands.

Comment: If there is already a CSS selector for `.a_class` at the time that the new element is loaded, it should immediately be updated to the style in that class.

Comment: Just move it to css file and the ajax content with the specific class names will be applied with the properties defined. The mistake might be that you didn't select the div element correctly with classname or id.

Comment: It works now! I just made sure that the script runs after loading completes..

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the raw html into a temporary element in memory and manipulate it there before inserting in the DOM

```js
const fakeFetch = () =>{
  return new Promise(res=> res('<div class="a_class" id="a_id">Text</div>'))

}

fakeFetch().then(html => {
  const temp = document.createElement('div');
  temp.innerHTML = html;
  temp.querySelectorAll('.a_class').forEach(el => el.classList.remove('a_class'))
  const res = temp.innerHTML;
  document.querySelector('#container').innerHTML += res

  console.log(res)
})
```

```css
.a_class{color:red}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```